# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win10toast' in exe file

Tags: python, exe

I packaged my py file into an exe file with this command in python terminal:

`pyinstaller --onefile reminder.py`

The `py` file already have the module installed but the `exe` file have `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win10toast' when running`. Here is the content of the `reminder.py`:

```
import time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

# code logics
```

I have tried reinstall the **win10toast** library with `pip install` command and change my python interpreter before packaging the py file, none of it work.

Here is the error log:

```
File "reminder.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win10toast'
[25352] Failed to execute script 'reminder' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: Could you add the complete error log please?

Comment: @Linux Sure, I have updated the error log into the question

Comment: I think the error could be because sometimes PyInstaller does not include all the required dependencies. So maybe you could try `--hiden-import` when running PyInstaller. `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import win10toast reminder.py`

Comment: @Linux I tried this method, but the error still persist.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. There might be another option using a hook file to handle the import. First you must create a file named `hook-win10toast.py` in the same directory as `reminder.py`. Inside that file write these two lines `from PyInstaller.utils.hook import collect_submodules`and `hiddenimports=collect_submodules('win10toast')`. Generate new executable (without hiddenimport).

Comment: @Linux I have tried this method and package the 2 py file together, but it still have the same error. `pyinstaller --onefile  reminder.py hook-win10toast.py`